# How to get current user name in jsf page with shiro?

Tags: jsf-2, shiro

i am using shiro for security management in my jsf application and i was wondering how to get the current user name in jsf page, please advise.

i tried `<shiro:principal/>` but it always returns empty string although user is logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiro tags are for JSP, not for Facelets. Shiro is still hanging in J2EE era and needs to catch up the new world known as "Java EE" yet, including JSP's successor Facelets.

It's fortunately at least available the same way as with container managed authentication, via [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29):

```
<p>Welcome, #{request.remoteUser}</p>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF2 - Shiro tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html)

Comment: i also tried this jsf2 solution http://mjtoolbox.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0-for-shiro-authorization/ but it gives me exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.shiro.web.faces.tags.HasPermissionTag`

Comment: This is unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: i already tried `#{request.remoteUser}` but it gives result as `com.myapp.data.domain.User@bc570ec5` and it doesn't print current user name

Comment: This is impossible. Perhaps you're not running the code you think you're running, or you made the wrong observation (or `com.myapp.data.domain.User@bc570ec5` is really the whole login username and you made a design/configuration mistake somewhere).

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing an SSCCE. It's at least a major mistake. I recommend to put this project apart and take a pause on it for now and restart with a completely blank playground with help of the JSF2 - Shiro tutorial linked in "See also" section of the answer. This gives you the opportunity to play around with it the right way. Finally apply the lessons learnt on your real project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that allows you to use [shiro with JSF](https://github.com/deluan/shiro-faces):

```
    <repository>
        <id>bintray-deluan-maven</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/deluan/maven</url>
    </repository>
```

Then you can use:

```
<shiro:principal property="name"/>
```

But be careful! It is vulnerable to XSS!